# emacs で現在の読み込みエンコーディングを表示するには？

Tags: emacs

emacs で、今開いているファイルのエンコーディングを表示したいと考えました。
(emacs がそのファイルの読み取りの際に利用したエンコーディング)
これは、どうやったら実現できますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M-x describe-current-coding-system` はどうでしょうか。
現在開いているバッファのエンコーディングなど、Emacsが関わるエンコーディング設定を`*Help*`バッファに一覧表示します。

また、デフォルトではモードライン左端に現在の文字コード（と改行コード）が表示されています。これを確認するのが手っ取り早いかと思います。

- `-` undecided (ascii)
- `=` no-conversion (binary)
- `S` shift_jis
- `E` euc-jp
- `J` iso-2022
- `U` utf-8

[image: emacs-HELLO]

試しに`<help> h`でHELLOファイルを開くとスクリーンショットのように表示されます。

Answer (score 2):

さらに別解として、`describe-coding-system`ならデフォルトで`C-h C`に割り当てられているのでお手軽です。`Describe coding system:`というプロンプトで空Enterすると、上記の`describe-current-coding-system`が実行されます。

Answer (score 1):

オイラんちの emacs-23.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) では

```
(describe-variable 'buffer-file-coding-system)
```

でいけたっぽいです。
オイラの作った C# プロジェクトのソースファイルをテキトーに開いた結果、
デザイナが自動で作る `Resources.ja-JP.resx` に対しては `utf-8-with-signature-dos` とか
`cp932` で書いた `Program.cs` に対しては `japanese-shift-jis-dos` とか
が観測されました。

キー操作なら `M-x describe-variable` の後 `buffer-file-coding-system` っすね。

Comment: FWIW: `<f1> v` で describe-variable は実行できますね。